# Mazda 323: How to find OEM Part Numbers

Tags: mazda, parts

I have a [97 Mazda - 323 S V (BA) - 1.8 i 16V (114 Hp)](http://www.auto-data.net/en/?f=showCar&car_id=11162) and was wondering if there is a way to find out OEM part numbers other than running to the local Mazda dealership and begging them.

I mean, is there any reliable on line data base of part numbers for various model's and makes, or some other method for finding part numbers?

Comment: Not a true answer, but I use rockauto.com extensively, as they seem to have all the parts and numbers to go with them. If it were a GM product, I'd use gmpartsdirect.com as they have a great database as well. I don't know if there is anything like that for Mazda parts (or Ford parts for the crossover of that). I'll see if I can find something when I get home this evening.

Comment: @Paulster2 Just took a look at the rock auto site and it looks pretty nice, even though it doesn't seem to have oem part numbers, at least it gives me an idea of some compatible third party parts.

Answer (score 1):

I use rockauto.com extensively, as they seem to have all the parts and numbers to go with them. If it were a GM product, I'd use gmpartsdirect.com as they have a great database as well. I don't know if there is anything like that for Mazda parts (or Ford parts for the crossover of that). I'll see if I can find something when I get home this evening.

While looking on that site, if you look for Motocraft parts (for you Mazda), it should have the original part numbers for you. Also, on RockAuto, there will often be a "info" button just to the right of the part number. When you click that, there will usually be an OEM part number listed in there if they have one. I've seen it on about 75% of the products they stock. The OEM number may not be on *ever* part within a category, but it will usually be on *one* of them.